# print background with two different colores

Tags: php, colors

I need print "background" with two different colores. For example

```
1º <span background="#ccc"></span>
2º <span background="#000"></span>
3º <span background="#ccc"></span>
4º <span background="#000"></span>
5º <span background="#ccc"></span>
6º <span background="#000"></span>
...
```

Im using "Foreach". How can i Print it?

My code is:

```
  foreach ($inv as $invoi)
   {

    $valuer = 0;
    $valuer = 0 + $invoi["SOMA"];

       $str = str_replace('.', '', $valuer);


    $vale = number_format($valuer, 2, '.', '.') . "";

$plus = 5000000;
$minus = 0;


$totalnumber = $plus + $minus;

$pluspercent = round(($str / $plus) * 100);

$total = round($plus + $minus);
$totalVotes = $total;

$findmax = max($str); 
$findmin = min($str); 


$tbody .=  '<li><span style="background: #DifferentColor; bottom: 0; text-align: center; height:'.$pluspercent.'%">'.$vale.'</span></li>';



   }
```

I need make a graph, and i will add a different color for each bar, for example: black | white | black | white

Maybe someone can help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable before the for loop to hold the value of the color:

```
$currentcolor = '#ccc' 

//the for loop begin here
```

Display the current color:

```
$tbody .=  '<li><span style="background: ' . $currentcolor . '; bottom: 0; text-align: center; height:'.$pluspercent.'%">'.$vale.'</span></li>';
```

Finally, change the value of the color (at the end of for loop):

```
$currentcolor = $currentcolor == '#ccc' ? '#000' : '#ccc';
```

**EDIT:**
Here is full code:

```
$currentcolor = '#00db10'; 
$invlenght = count($inv);
$count = 0;

foreach ($inv as $invoi){

    //test if it is last iteration here
    if($count == $invlenght - 1){ $currentcolor = "#ff0000"; } 

    $valuer = $invoi["SOMA"];
    $date = $invoi["date"];

   $str = str_replace('.', '', $valuer);
   $vale = number_format($valuer, 2, '.', '.') . "";
   $plus = 4000000;
   $minus = 0;
   $totalnumber = $plus + $minus;

   $pluspercent = round(($str / $plus) * 100);

   $total = round($plus + $minus);
   $totalVotes = $total;

   $findmax = max($str); 
   $findmin = min($str); 

   $tbody .=  '<li><span style="background: ' . $currentcolor . '; bottom: 0; text-align:         center; height:'.$pluspercent.'%"><span class="showmonth">'.$showdate.'</span><span class="fixdivg">€'.$vale.' EUR</span></span></li>';


   $currentcolor = $currentcolor == '#00db10' ? '#00b90e' : '#00db10';
   $count++;
}
```